# Bing basemap missing from ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-online-basemaps, bing-maps

The Bing basemap seems to have been recently removed from the "Add Basemap" dialogue in ArcMap.  I'm using 10.1.  I've also heard reports from a coworker that a Bing basemap layer was replaced by a red exclamation mark in an existing document she was using.

Is this just a local problem on my end?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes,
Microsoft and esri will no longer provide the free service.

> [What's New for Arcgis Online March 2013](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisonline/whats-new) Register Bing Map key—Organizations who want to include Bing Maps
>   in their map viewer basemap gallery can add a Bing Map key to their
>   map configuration. This is related to the [phasing out of
>   complimentary use of Bing Maps](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgisonline/010q/010q00000006000000.htm#ESRI_SECTION2_DDCE6A7BD52243719B8F636700075406). For more information, [see
>   Configuring the map](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgisonline/010q/010q000000mm000000.htm).
>   [image: requ]

You can sign up for the microsoft license at...
[Microsoft Map Developers website](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/web.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There is a [patch available for 10.1 users](http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks/view/productid/160/metaid/2003), allowing proper use of Bing Keys to obtain the Bing Basemap.

To obtain the Bing Key, an MSDN / Bing account is required for gathering either the 90 day free trial or a Basic (paid) or Enterprise (paid) subscription.